# Vertical alignment of text and icon

Tags: codenameone

Today I spent two hours trying to align vertically the text of a toogle button at the bottom of the button icon.

The button icon height is a three or four times longer than the text height: the text must be vertically aligned at the bottom of the icon.

The method setVerticalAlignment(int valign) works as expect if the parameter is Component.TOP or Component.CENTER, but Component.BOTTOM acts exactly as Component.CENTER.

I tried a lot of workarounds, without success. It’s odd that a so easy task is hard to do: am I missing something? Thank you.

I don’t know if it’s relevant, however I’m also using setTextPosition(Component.RIGHT).

Comment: Another detail is that the icon is a multimage png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer...

That code is a bit difficult to work with and has so many nuances and misbehavior's. I usually end up just splitting the text and icon to separate labels and using something like a flow layout:

```
Form hi = new Form("Big and Small", BoxLayout.y());

CheckBox toggle = CheckBox.createToggle("My Text");
toggle.setUIID("Label");
Label bigIcon = new Label("");
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(bigIcon, FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO, 10);

Container lead = FlowLayout.encloseBottomInRow(toggle, bigIcon);
lead.setUIID("ToggleButton");
lead.setLeadComponent(toggle);
hi.add(lead);

hi.show();
```

Note that at this time this code requires a change that was added yesterday to the code (the ByRow method). Initially I thought this was a bug in `FlowLayout` but it seems it was just two different ways of calculating vertical alignment for the container.

[image]

To get a sense of why aligning and placing labels is so hard check out this code responsible for that: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/fd2acfc10eb22f4b7a3089aeac4e967280f92b4e/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/plaf/DefaultLookAndFeel.java#L1314-L1623

This is just the generic code. There are copies of it in native iOS and Android code (for performance).

Comment: Thank you, however `Container main = FlowLayout.encloseBottom(icon, toggleBtn);` doesn't work, it vertically aligns on TOP instead of BOTTOM. Luckily, I've found a solution, which is: `Container main = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(BoxLayout.encloseX(icon, BoxLayout.encloseYBottom(toggleBtn)));`. It seems that `FlowLayout` assign a wrong size to the `toggleBtn`, while `BoxLayout.encloseX(icon, BoxLayout.encloseYBottom(toggleBtn))` assigns the correct size to the components, that is necessary for the wanted alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. It seems there's a bug in that method, I edited the answer

Comment: It seems I made a mistake with the "fix" for `FlowLayout`. It was working fine. There are just two distinct ways to calculate height and both are important.

Comment: So is my worrkaround `Container main = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(BoxLayout.encloseX(icon, BoxLayout.encloseYBottom(toggleBtn)));` the only solution, or is FlowLayout now correctly fixed?

Comment: You can use `FlowLayout.encloseBottomInRow` as I showed in the edited code. It should work as expected.